# Android app behaving unexpectedly after calling System.exit(0)

Tags: android, android-activity, exit

I'm writing a simple app with 4 activities. I'll describe it quickly so you understand what I'm trying to achieve.

First activity - MainActivity has some TextEdit fields that collect 2 input parameters - number of reps and length of pause in seconds. A button takes me to the second activity:
WorkActivity - all this does is it starts counting until I press 'done' then it either calls PauseActivity, or if it has been the last rep, calls OverviewActivity.
PauseActivity counts down the seconds until next rep, then beeps at me to let me know it's time, and shows WorkActivity again.
OverviewActivity shows total workout time and times for each rep.

It also features a button that should just end the app. I know exiting your apps is not really in line with the Android application life cycle philosophy, but I need it (or something like it to happen).
I have a singleton controller class that keeps track of the reps and logs the time. I can kill this instance (or fake its death, so a new one will be created), but when I "close" the app and then click it again, I get the OverviewActivity instead of the expected MainActivity.

I expected that calling System.exit(0) would take care of things, simply shut down the application, so it will have to initialize anew when run again. Instead the whole thing started acting really derpy. When I click the button that calls System.exit(0), instead of vanishing my app sort of restarts. It shows the WorkActivity, and starts counting. When I click the done button (which should take me to PauseActivity) I get an exception. The application crashes - and then restarts again. This will repeat until I hit the homescreen button, and the app remains in this useless state until I kill it in application manager.

Also, I'm not exactly sure, but I think the System.exit(0) call (or the subsequent crash) disconnects the debugger, cause I've been unable to get Eclipse to hit any breakpoints afterwards. This means I can't really see the actual exception that occurs.

Can someone shed some light on this? Is there a way to use System.exit(0) correctly?

In the absence of this option, what would be the correct way of handling this?
I need the app to:
- when I click the final 'Done' button the Home button or the Back button, dispose of the Controller, (and everything else if possible), stop counting (if any timer is running) and essentially shut itself down)
- when I click the app's icon again, to show me a new instance (or one that appears new) with the MainActivity to greet me and all other activities in their default state.

Answer (score 5):

Using System.exit(0) is a bad practice.

> Calling exit() in this case would terminate the process, killing your
>   other component and potentially corrupting your data. The OS could
>   care less of course, but your users might not appreciate it.
>
> Killing voluntarily your process will not help other applications, if
>   they have exhausted their internal Dalvik heap limit. No matter how
>   much physical memory a device has, the OS has a limit on how much
>   memory Dalvik is allowed to use in any process for heap allocations.
>   Thus, it is possible that the system has free half of its memory and a
>   particular application still hits OOM.

Do not use System.exit(0); instead you can just use finish().

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Comment: I see. So how do I make sure that my MainActivity is displayed the next time the user clicks on the app's icon? And how do I make my app disappear when it supposedly "exits"?

Comment: you set from AndroidManifest your main activity like this   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

and to make it dissapear use finish(); - finish will "terminate" an activity

Comment: This is what I have in AndroidManifest: <activity
            android:name="....MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>. It was set up this way by Eclipse. Also, as I stated before I have 4 activities, calling finish() at the end will just cause one of the other activities to show up.